# load @next/swc-win32-ia32-msvc, but an error occurred: a dynamic link library (dll) initialization routine failed

Tags: node.js, dll, next.js13, swc-compiler

After running

```
npm run dev`
```

(nextjs app)

the result was this

▲ Next.js 14.0.3

- Local:        http://localhost:3000

⚠ Attempted to load @next/swc-win32-ia32-msvc, but an error occurred: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

...\node_modules@next\swc-win32-ia32-msvc\next-swc.win32-ia32-msvc.node⨯ Failed to load SWC binary for win32/ia32, see more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/failed-loading-swc

how to solve this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by re-installing node x64 instead of x84. mistakenly I have not installed the compatible node version

Answer (score 2):

I was using the Windows 11 64-bit operating system. I installed node 32bit and saw the same error you have.
Here is what I did to solve the problem.

- First, I remove install node 32bit.
- [install Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable chose 2015, 2017, 2019, and 2022 x64](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist)
- and then installed node 64bit and everything worked for me.

If you already have node 64 installed, you should install it  Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable

Answer (score 1):

Yes the very first method of uninstalling node 32 and installing node 64 works  also make sure you are running it via `**npm run dev**`  and not npm start or next start

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me.

- Remove the old node (x32)
- I install Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable chose 2015, 2017, 2019, and 2022 x64 as said in one of the comments above
- I installed the x64 node

Answer (score 0):

**I was facing the same error while using the Nextjs.**

[image]

This is how I handled this error:
You need to update your nodejs version, You should use Node v20 and 64-bit.

**Step 1:** Uninstall the existing nodejs

**Step 2:** Install the Latest Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Version from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170

**Step 3:** Install Nodejs v20+ and 64-bit from here https://nodejs.org/en/download

**Step 4:** Restart the system

**Step 5:** Run command `npm run dev`

[image]

**Output:**

[image]